# Ethernet : mismatch between diff pairs

Tags: pcb, ethernet

I am designing a 4- layer PCB with  Ethernet (RMI) and integrated magnetics, which I want to make as good as possible with respect to signal integrity and EMC.
RMI, so the frequency is 50 mHz.
Because of practical reasons I have a length mismatch between the Tx+- and Rx+- diff pairs of about 4 inch. (**Note : only a mismatch between the pairs but not within one pair**)

I found a lot of information online and on this website about length matching between Tx + and Tx - or Rx+ and Rx-, **but not** about the length mismatch between the two pairs (intra pair if I am correct).

Question : What effects does this mismatch have? Do I need to care about it with only 4 inches ?
If not, in which situation would I need to take into account ? and how?

Comment: 10baseT? 100baseT?

Answer (score 3):

Ethernet RX and TX pairs have literally nothing to do with one another. It's a full duplex channel. You would never need to concern yourself with this, because they are independent.

Comment: So because it is a duplex channel it does not matter if lengths are completely mismatched?

Comment: yea, they are separate, asynchronous, channels for sending and receiving data. The senders and receivers of data don't know anything about each other, or the routing topology a particular packet will follow between them, so how _could_ the phase of information passing between them matter?